# How can I execute a binary through ruby for a limited time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command

I want to run a binary through ruby for a limited time. In my case its `airodump-ng` with the full command of:

```
airodump-ng -c <mychan> mon0 --essid "my_wlan" --write capture
```

For the ones who don't know `airdump-ng` for normal it starts and doesn't terminate itself. Its running forever if the user doesn't stop it by pressing Strg + C. This isn't a problem at the bash but executing it through ruby it's causing serious trouble. Is there a way to limit the time a binary is runned by the `system` method?

Answer (score 2):

Try timeout library:

```
require 'timeout'

begin
  Timeout.timeout(30) do
    system('airodump-ng -c <mychan> mon0 --essid "my_wlan" --write capture')
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  # timeout
end
```

Comment: Ah, you got there first! :) I'll delete my duplicate answer.

Comment: Thank you, this worked in the theory. I tested it and in the ruby source the `Timeout::Error` was rescued. But that didn't stop airdump-ng from running further. What I of cause can do is killing the process in the rescue block but thats not really the solution of my dreams...

Comment: I am not sure if it's a perfect solution but you can use `pid = Process.spawn('airodump-ng -c <mychan> mon0 --essid "my_wlan" --write capture')`. This will give you process pid. You can kill it with `Process.kill('TERM', pid)`

Comment: This also doesn't work. Actually aircrack-ng simply goes on running. Maybe the process directly spawned by the command is killed but there is another process that detatched itself from this process.

Comment: You can output pid from spawn method and compare it with running airodump pid. Maybe you should use different signal.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Ruby `spawn` method. From the Ruby docs:

> This method is similar to #system but it doesn’t wait for the command to finish.

Something like this:

```
# Start airodump
pid = spawn('airodump-ng -c <mychan> mon0 --essid "my_wlan" --write capture')
# Wait a little while...
sleep 60
# Then stop airodump (similar to pressing CTRL-C)
Process.kill("INT", pid)
```